# Create new column based on group-by function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Alan', 'Alan', 'Steve', 'Steve'],
                'ID': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                'Value': ['Y','Y','Y','N','N','N','Y','N','N','Y']})


Name    ID    Value   
 Bob     1       Y          
 Bob     2       Y          
 Bob     3       Y          
 Joe     4       N          
 Joe     5       N          
 Joe     6       N
 Alan    7       Y
 Alan    8       N
 Steve   9       N
 Steve   10      Y
```

I need to compute a new `Result` column that has the following rule. For each group `Name` so Bob, Joe, etc., if each `Value` is 'Y', assign each value a Y in the new column. Otherwise, assign it a 'N'.

So ideal output is:

```
 Name    ID    Value   Result
 Bob     1       Y       Y
 Bob     2       Y       Y  
 Bob     3       Y       Y  
 Joe     4       N       N  
 Joe     5       N       N  
 Joe     6       N       N
 Alan    7       Y       N
 Alan    8       N       N
 Steve   9       N       N
 Steve   10      Y       N
```

This is what I have so far but doesn't work correctly.

```
df1['Result'] = df1.groupby('Name').Value.all().reindex(df1.Name).astype(str).values
df1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close! Here's how you could do it:

```
df1["Result"] = df1.groupby("Name").Value.transform(lambda value: all(value == "Y"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for `Series` with same size like original and [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html):

```
df1['Result'] = np.where(df1['Value'].eq('Y').groupby(df1['Name']).transform('all'), 'Y', 'N')
```

Alternative:

```
mask = df1['Value'].eq('Y').groupby(df1['Name']).transform('all')
df1.loc[~mask, 'Value'] = 'N'
```

Or get all groups with at least `N` and replace by `N` by `mask` with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
mask = df1['Name'].isin(df1.loc[df1['Value'].eq('N'), 'Name'])
df1.loc[mask, 'Value'] = 'N'
```

---

```
print (df1)
    Name  ID Value
0    Bob   1     Y
1    Bob   2     Y
2    Bob   3     Y
3    Joe   4     N
4    Joe   5     N
5    Joe   6     N
6   Alan   7     N
7   Alan   8     N
8  Steve   9     N
9  Steve  10     N
```